# Which is correct

Tags: word-choice

I want to know which sentence is correct "I know what you are doing and with who" or "I know what you are doing and with whom"

Comment: @Mari-LouA   Earlier this week the New York Times' website was using "Whom do the the Shopping Malls of Brazil Belong to" to tease an otherwise well-titled essay.  While I understand the grammatical relationships, I did re-read it and ask myself if there shouldn't be some sort of Proximity Rule.

Answer (score 1):

"And with whom" is correct.  *Whom* is the object of the preposition *with*.

Comment: I thought that was correct and that is what I used before I got an answer, but I really appreciate the help.  Thank you

Comment: Technically I agree that *whom* makes sense here. But in spoken day-to-day language, I think the first would be more common.